# Custom Bugzilla hook not invoked when using mod_perl

Tags: perl, bugzilla, mod-perl

I have added a custom hook to `Bugzilla/Install/Util.pm`:

```
# Used by template_include_path.
sub _template_base_directories {
    # ...
    Bugzilla::Hook::process('template_dirs_alter', { template_dirs => \@template_dirs });
    # ...
    return \@template_dirs;
}
```

When executed via cgi, everything works fine, but using `mod_perl` I can see using `warn()` statements that the process statement above is executed for the custom hook, but the actual hook implementation is never invoked.

In `Bugzilla/Hook.pm`:

```
sub process {
    my ($name, $args) = @_;
    # ...

    foreach my $extension (@{ Bugzilla->extensions }) {
        if ($extension->can($name)) {
            # log shows the expected hook name and extension
            # so the hook implementation is found
            $extension->$name($args); # should invoke hook implementation, but doesn't
        }
    }
    # ...
}
```

The hook is implemented in an Extension.pm like so:

```
sub template_dirs_alter {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my ($template_dirs) = @$args{qw(template_dirs)};

    if($something) {
        push(@$template_dirs, "some/dir/path");
    }
}
```

Any obvious gotchas with mod_perl and/or the Bugzilla hook/extension system I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `cwd` is usually the Bugzilla root when using `cgi`, it can be anything when using `mod_perl` (e.g. the apache home).

When using file paths in Bugzilla extensions, always **prefix relative paths**:

```
use File::Basename qw(dirname);
our $BASEDIR = dirname(__FILE__);

sub template_dirs_alter {
    my ($self, $args) = @_;
    my ($template_dirs) = @$args{qw(template_dirs)};

    if($something) {
        push(@$template_dirs, $BASEDIR . "some/dir/path");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `_template_base_directories()` is called before `extensions` are `loaded` under `mod_perl`. If that's the case, it's a bug and should be fixed.

Comment: thank you, I've checked the execution order and my logs tell me you are right.

Comment: one thing I fail to understand though: how can `if ($extension->can($name))` evaluate to true, if the code is not loaded?

Comment: turns out the issue was much simpler: mod_perl sets a different cwd compared to using cgi. Combine this with relative paths and you have the problem